# Which variant of "you can't have your cake and eat it too" would you personally use?

Tags: usage

I've come to know recently that the phrase in question has many forms. For example,

> You can't have your cake and eat it, too
>
> You can't eat your cake and have it, too
>
> You can't eat your cake and still keep it.

And also I'd like to know which of these is commoner in UK, USA, and Canada.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker in Canada, I have only ever heard "You can't have your cake and eat it too".

I've never liked this idiom. I've never actually understood why it means what it means until I read [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_can%27t_have_your_cake_and_eat_it) about it just now. That article actually discusses why it's commonly misunderstood.